# Cannot get cron.php /cron.sh to run via cronjob

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, crontab

I'm really struggling with the below cron job and any help would be appreciated. I'm running Magento and I'm trying to run cron.php every minute through a cron job. I now understand that you should use cron.sh which I've also tested below.

I can log into SSH and run any of the following commands and they all work as they should, forgot password emails sent / new products created from an import etc:

```
/usr/bin/sh /home/thefootb/public_html/cron.sh cron.php --mode=always
/usr/bin/sh /home/thefootb/public_html/cron.sh cron.php --mode=default
/usr/bin/php /home/thefootb/public_html/cron.php
```

But when I but these into a cron job (logging into SSH and using crontab -e) nothing happens. Here's my crontab file:

```
SHELL="/bin/bash"
* * * * * /usr/bin/sh /home/thefootb/public_html/cron.sh cron.php --mode=always
* * * * * /usr/bin/sh /home/thefootb/public_html/cron.sh cron.php --mode=default
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/thefootb/public_html/cron.php
```

I've also tried:

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/thefootb/public_html/cron.php
```

As I this is what my host advised me.

I'm really stuck with this - it should be so simple but it just won't work.

Thanks in advance
Chris

Comment: Might be the issue with PATH variable.  Can you try it by adding PATH variable in your cron.php and execute it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple versions of PHP installed you need to specify which version you want manually. The version of PHP the is used for web visitors is not necessarily the same version that is used for CLI or cron. Here's how you could do cron with the explicit PHP version specified (replace `/opt/remi/php70/root/usr/bin` with your particular path):

```
    /opt/remi/php70/root/usr/bin/php -c /home/thefootb/public_html/cron.php
```

*FYI: `php -c` specifies look for php.ini in this particular directory. See [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php).*